Python Two Sum Logic Error: Getting Incorrect Output Indices"
I just started working on LeetCode problems and I'm enc
ountering a logic error in the Two Sum problem. I believe my code is correct, but it's returning incorrect indices.
Here’s the code I wrote:
class Solution(object):
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        self.number=nums
        self.length=len(self.number)
        self.target=int(target)
        for i in range(self.length):
            for j in range(i+1,self.length):
                if self.number[i]+self.number[j]==self.target:
                    return [i,j]
        return("Error")
number=input("Enter list")
target=input("Enter the target")
solution=Solution()
index=solution.twoSum(number,target)

When I test this with the input list [2, 7, 11, 15] and target 9, it gives an output of [1, 2] instead of the expected [0, 1].
I suspect the issue might be related to how I'm handling the input. How can I fix this to ensure it returns the correct indices?

What is the "Two Sum Problem"?

What have you done to check that you are "handling the input" correctly?

If it's returning the wrong indices then it's probably not correct

Presumably you know that input() returns a String not a List or a number. So how are you handling that?

The LeetCode twoSum function has the following signature: def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]: Your code doesn't seem to account for that

Just convert the nums to a set, and then for every number n in nums, check if (target - n) exists in the set. Trivially done in O(n) time.

For reference: the problem statement, in short, is that you are given a list of numbers. You are to return the indices of two numbers in that list that add up to a target given. So e.g., input = [2, 7, 11, 15] and target = 9, since 2 + 7 = 9, then the result will be [0, 1], the indices of the numbers that add up to 9.

The Answer
Phew. Now, let's look at the most obvious problem at hand: yup, you're definitely treating the input incorrectly. You are taking the input using the builtin input() function, which doesn't convert lists you type to actual lists - they are just strings, so when you loop over the string, you only get back the characters one by one. An obvious solution to this is just to define the list in the code, as such: numbers = [2, 7, 11, 15]. Now it works!
Another solution is to still accept user input in the list format (without square brackets). This rather nasty one-liner numbers = [int(n) for n in input('Enter numbers, separated by commas: ').split(',')] should work pretty well.

Unnecessary Style Yap
Side note: the code formatting. According to the widely accepted Python style guide, [PEP8], your code (https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) has a whole whopping unacceptable obnoxious 14 problems!
Jokes aside, ignoring the problem of LeetCode requiring you to specifically name the function as such, style problems in your code include:

E225: Missing spaces before and after equal signs ("operators") (suggested: target = input(...))
E231: Missing space after commas (suggested: return [i, j])
E275: Missing space after return ("keywords") (suggested: return "Error")
E305: Missing two empty lines after function (or class) definitions
Suggestion: Remove the redundant/unnecessary brackets on line 10.
You don't need to take on I/O manually in LeetCode.

Here's the final code according to my suggestions:
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums, _target):
        length = len(nums)
        _target = int(_target)
        for i in range(length):
            for j in range(i+1, length):
                if nums[i]+nums[j] == _target:
                    return [i, j]

        return "Error"

At runtime:

Input: 2, 7, 11, 15.
Input: 9.
Output: [0, 1].

Works perfectly fine.

There's no need to use .strip(). int() will ignore surrounding whitespace.

@Barmar Ah. Forgot about that, thanks for telling me.

Why _target instead of target? That doesn't shadow anything, does it? Also it would probably be better to edit the problem description into the question than include it in your answer.

There is no need to return "Error" as the Leetcode challenge allows for the assumption that there will be exactly one correct answer.

There exists a trivial linear-time solution, no need for a quadratic-time solution. See my comment in the original post.

Even if you fix the error in how you're handling the list (which Leetcode sets up for you):
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        length = len(nums)
        target = int(target)
        for i in range(length):
            for j in range(i + 1, length):
                if nums[i] + nums[j] == target:
                    return [i, j]

Then your solution still won't be accepted by Leetcode because they won't test with a small list. They'll test with very large lists. From the challenge page, we can see that in the constraints:
Correction: your solution will be accepted by Leetcode, but it will take substantially longer that a solution like the below. In my testing: 0ms vs. 1745ms.

Constraints:

2 <= nums.length <= 104
-109 <= nums[i] <= 109
-109 <= target <= 109


With a list this large, the O(n2) complexity of your solution will take much more time than necessary. This is not apparent when you test on a very small list.
Instead you need to do something more efficient. If you keep a dictionary where values are used to index indices in the original list, you can lookup the index of any list element's complementary (to target) element in O(1) complexity. This yields a very fast O(n) algorithm vs. your O(n2) approach.
An example implementation:
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        d = {}
        for i, x in enumerate(nums):
            a = d.get(target-x, None)
            if a is not None: return [a, i]
            d[x] = i


Actually, that solution is accepted by LeetCode. O(n^2) is acceptable when n is at most 10^4. 10^5 tends to be the actual turning point.

there are few problems, try the below code
def twoSum():
    #just enter list as '12345' excluding ','
    num_arr=input("enter the Array")
    #using a list to store the result of i,j format
    res_arr=[]*2
    #target to find from sum of 2 items in array
    target=int(input("Enter the target"))
    for i in range(len(num_arr)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(num_arr)):
            #using int() to convert string to integer for comparing with 'target',which is an integer
            if int(num_arr[i])+int(num_arr[j])==target: 
                res_arr.append(i)
                res_arr.append(j)
                break;
    if len(res_arr)<1:
        print("no target found!")
    else:
        print(res_arr)
        
class solution():
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        twoSum()

:
The problem with your code as I noticed is 

The return code wasn't displaying the i,j values so i used print() function,and 

3.The only extra thing i did is add a condition to 'print()' rather than 'return' and another list to add the i,j values (which i don't think matters considering Space complexity in leetcode).
That's it.

Don't just post code. Explain what the problems are, and how you fixed them.

sorry i was busy so couldn't do it,I edited my reply with explanation as much I understood.
